# DSP - practical even or odd functions

Tags: dsp

Signals can be classified as even, odd, or a neither - in which case they can be broken up into their even and odd components. Theoretically its all very nice to be able to say that yes that function is symmetric about the origin, but practically is this ever actually achievable?

My confusion basically is how can a practical signal exist before t = 0 or x[0] and thus allow for classification? In my naive thinking it would seem that you can never have a purely even or odd signal in practice.

EDIT: To clarify, this is about an INPUT

Comment: Well I'd say that sine and cosine waves are the arch-type even and odd functions.  How does my sine wave exist before I turn my function generator on?

Comment: exactly my question - theoretically you can draw a nice sine wave starting at whatever negative time you want, but practically if I'm sampling something it will start at t = 0, and then the usual -x(t) = x(-t) test can't really be used. of course if you have the entire signal already you can rearrange samples however you like, but real time is where my I'm confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a real signal, the choice of exactly which instant constitutes t = 0 is essentially arbitrary. So, for instance, if a signal occurs from 9:00:00 AM day before yesterday, to 9:00:02 AM the same day, you can set t = 0 at 9:00:01 and know what the signal was for t < 0 as well as you do for t > 0.

Comment: okay.does that mean that if you are sampling a real time signal and have a suitable delay, you can essentially do the same thing and choose a t = 0?

Comment: Absolutely. That's what you do, for instance, with a digital scope. You can set a trigger point, and then have that point occur anywhere in the trace: beginning, end, or middle. Once the samples are in memory it's all the same.